# How to assign value to Numbers in Array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop

Hey everyone so I have an Array `private var frames:Array;` which I give value and initiate in my constructor function like so `frames = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];`

Now I am trying to give a string value to each number in the array for my hitTest Function. I was thinking something on the lines of a for loop and giving them values there but having some issues here is what I have so far:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
        {
           var currentFrameNumber = frames[i];

            //assign values to numbers in array
           if (currentFrameNumber == 2)
           {
               trace("2_RED");
               currentWires.sRed = "RED";
           }
           if (currentFrameNumber == 3)
           {
               trace("GREEN");
               currentWires.sGreen = "GREEN";
           }
           if (currentFrameNumber == 4)
           {
               trace("BLUE");
               currentWires.sBlue = "BLUE";
           }
           if (currentFrameNumber == 5)
           {
               trace("YELLOW");
               currentWires.sYellow = "YELLOW";
           }
           if (currentFrameNumber == 6)
           {
               trace("WHITE");
               currentWires.sWhite = "WHITE";
           }
           if (currentFrameNumber == 7)
           {
               trace("PURPLE");
               currentWires.sPurple = "PURPLE";
           }
           if (currentFrameNumber == 8)
           {
               trace("BLACK");
               currentWires.sBlack = "BLACK";
           }
        }
```

this doesn't work at all. I know I Am missing something crucial. Please any help would be appreciated thanks!

****************UPDATE****************

I have my array of Movie clips like so `aClockArray = [playScreen.wire_5, playScreen.wire_6, playScreen.wire_7, playScreen.wire_8];`

in my last post I finally figure out how to randomize the array with no repeat like so:

```
//Loop through wires and make them randomn generate color
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aClockArray.length; i++)
        {
           var currentWires = aClockArray[i];
           var randomFrame:uint = frames.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * frames.length), 1);


           //nWire = randomNumber(2, 8);

           currentWires.gotoAndStop(randomFrame);
           }
```

and above in my `frames` for loop is where I assign the values to the numbers in the `frames` array for my hitTest which I try to accomplish like so:

```
private function wireHitTestFunction():void 
    {
        //Loop through wires and make them randomn generate color
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aClockArray.length; i++)
        {
           var currentWires = aClockArray[i];

           if (redCopper.hitTestObject(currentWires) && currentWires.sRed == "RED")
           {
               //trace("HIT_ RED");
               hasRedWire = false;
               redCopper.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, redWireFunction);
               redWire.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, redWireFunction);
                trace("HIT");

           }
           if (blueCopper.hitTestObject(currentWires) && currentWires.sBlue == "BLUE")
           {
               //trace("HIT_BLUE");
               hasBlueWire = false;
               blueCopper.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, blueWireFunction);
               blueWire.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, blueWireFunction);
                trace("HIT");
           }
```

I cant seem to figure this out lost in code haha. I probably have it set up really badly.

basically the game is I have 7 colored wires on the stage that the user can drag and place inside the correct color slot. It was working fine until I had added the `var randomFrame:uint = frames.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * frames.length), 1);` I had to change things around. It was working fine when my original code was like so:

```
//Loop through wires and make them randomn generate color
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aClockArray.length; i++)
        {
           var currentWires = aClockArray[i];
           //var randomFrame:uint = frames.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * frames.length), 1);


           nWire = randomNumber(2, 8);

           currentWires.gotoAndStop(nWire);

           //If any of the Wires lands on 2,3,etc.. Assign Color for Hit Test
           if (nWire == 2)
           {
               trace("2_RED");
               currentWires.sRed = "RED";
           }
           if (nWire == 3)
           {
               trace("GREEN");
               currentWires.sGreen = "GREEN";
           }
           if (nWire == 4)
           {
               trace("BLUE");
               currentWires.sBlue = "BLUE";
           }
           if (nWire == 5)
           {
               trace("YELLOW");
               currentWires.sYellow = "YELLOW";
           }
           if (nWire == 6)
           {
               trace("WHITE");
               currentWires.sWhite = "WHITE";
           }
           if (nWire == 7)
           {
               trace("PURPLE");
               currentWires.sPurple = "PURPLE";
           }
           if (nWire == 8)
           {
               trace("BLACK");
               currentWires.sBlack = "BLACK";
           }
        }
```

Comment: And what are the "some issues" you are having?

Comment: I added an update above @Aaron It might be confusing to understand. The issues I am having is with the color coordinated hit Test. The random generated numbers are to stop on a certain frame in my clockArray each frame has a certain color. I have my colored wires which I want to hit Test with the same colored slots in the clock array but its not working that way at all:

Comment: NVM got it thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what issue you're seeing, and it's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing the entire code, but I'll take a stab at it...

rather than `currentWire.sRed = "RED";`

use a single variable to represent the current color, like so:

`currentWire.color = "RED";`

then..

```
if (redCopper.hitTestObject(currentWires) && currentWires.color== "RED")
{
     //trace("HIT_ RED");
     hasRedWire = false;
     redCopper.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, redWireFunction);
     redWire.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, redWireFunction);
     trace("HIT"); 
}
if (blueCopper.hitTestObject(currentWires) && currentWires.color== "BLUE")
{
    //trace("HIT_BLUE");
    hasBlueWire = false;
    blueCopper.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, blueWireFunction);
    blueWire.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, blueWireFunction);
    trace("HIT");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks I just fixed some code up with this made it simpler but still getting the same issues. Ahh Been at this for hours now. I am trying assign the number values in the array these string colors which work with my old code. But with my new code which generates random numbers with no repeats It all fails/. Ill have to try to figure this out somehow.

Comment: Would love to help, but I'm not sure what "it all fails" means.  I'm assuming you don't mean that it generates compiler errors.  If you could describe what actually happens when you run it, that would help.

Comment: Hey @Duggulous I figured it out thanks so much. It was something so simple like always

Comment: One thing to be aware of: the second parameter to Array.splice() tells how many objects to delete from the Array.  

The way the new code avoids repeating the same number is by removing that number from the Array.  

So eventually, the array will be empty.

Comment: Ah, congrats!  
You should post the solution as an answer to your own question and then mark it as accepted.